# C programming (reading information from file to variables)

Tags: c

How would I read information from a file to variables if I don't know how long it's gonna be.

Example of file:

```
student name
class grade credits
class grade credits
class grade credits
```

How would I save this info from this file if the number of classes varied. I need to print this information to the screen, while using the grades and number of credits to calculate a students GPA.

Comment: where is your code? where is the actual example of the input file?  where is the example of the expected output?  When asking a question, be clear about if it is a runtime or a compile time problem.  Supply the necessary details, as outlined in the 'help' section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed by fluter, `fgets` will allow you read the file line by line. `getline` is another (better IMHO) solution, it's [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) provides a simple usage example.

Then inside the reading loop, you have several options. I suggest you [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) applied on the line read.
It returns the number of items read. In this kind of simple case, I usually try to scan the line with different format strings and check the number of items read to verify if the line matched.

For example, you could use something like:

- "%s" as the format string for student name lines
- "%s %c %d" as the format string for grade lines

And I suggest you to compute the GPA inside the loop, this way, you shouldn't have to store the grades, if I'm correct.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do is to scan the input file until it meet the end of file or `EOF`, so you know you have reached the end of the file.
Something like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("grade.txt", "r");
if (!fp) {  exit(1); }
char line[1024];
char name[1024];
char *s;
s = fgets(line, sizeof line, fp);
if (!s) { fclose(fp); exit(0); }
strcpy(name, line);
do {
    s = fgets(line, sizeof line, fp);
    // convert line to grade, to integer or double as you want
} while (s != NULL);
// compute the GPA
```